# Repeating flash data in redirecting route?

Tags: laravel-5

I remember in CodeIgniter there used to be a way, to force all flash data to the next request.

Is there such functionality in Laravel?

I have a route, that all it does is redirects, and if there's is any flash data, it 'disappears' there, and is not passed on to the request where it could actually be shown.

I know i can use `redirect()->with('key', 'value')`, but it would be nice to just have a way, to simply 're flash', any flash data, as it may or may not exist, and could be few different keys (that I might or might not know)

Answer (score 0):

What you could do before your redirect() use:

```
$request->flash()
```

Your request will be stored inside the session

To retrieve flashed input from the previous request, use the old method on the Request instance. The old method will pull the previously flashed input data from the session:

```
$username = $request->old('username');
```

For more information:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

and scroll down to **Flashing Input To The Session**

Hope this helps!